# Django Sending HTML Table to Python

Tags: python, django

**Hello Guys**

I'm working with Django and I have a big doubt, i have 3 HTML tables and i need save this data in mysql, that table is filled by users and im not sure how can i sending the tables to python.

i tried using Ajax, but, really I'm not sure how to use it.

HTML CODE from one of my 3 tables:

custom.html

```
<table id="idTable" name="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>FIRST</th>
<th>Second</th>
   <tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ajaxFunction()" id="IDButton">Touch me!</button>
```

The tbody rows are added with javascript

Ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(){
var request = $.ajax({
url: window.location.href,
type: 'get',
data: {data1: "hello"},
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
request.done(function(data)){
console.log("works")
});
</script>
```

When i click the button in the console i can see "works" but in python is not working

Python code:
crm/views.py

```
def custom(request, op_id):
     if request.method == "GET":
          IF request.is_ajax():
                 message ="Yes"
          else:
                 message="No"
     return render(request, "custom.html")
```

I don't know why function is_ajax does not works.

I only wanna find a way to do this,
i will be glad !!!! 
Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to use AJAX? I think the best starting point as a beginner would be an HTML form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP\_X\_REQUESTED\_WITH not set in ajax call with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681767/http-x-requested-with-not-set-in-ajax-call-with-jquery)

Comment: Based on the duplicate it would seem that you could fix your problem using `$.get`.

Comment: Oh God,  HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH solved my problem
i needed use special headers how this guy explain about recognize the  function "is_ajax()"  , i can continue with my code like that 
javascript code 
var pokemon = ["Charmander", "Bulbasaur" , "Squirtle"]
data : {'pokemon' : pokemon},
function (data){
console.log(data) 
}
python code
in request.is_ajax():
 datos = request.GET.getlist('pokemon[]')
 return HttpResponse(datos)

console result (CharmanderBulbasaurSquirtle)

THANK YOU VERY MUCH, I CAN CONTINUE WITH MY PROJECT !!!!